# Idiomatic scala to process either file A or file B?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, idioms

I've got some code that does this:

```
for d in directories:  
    if d/f1 exists: process d/f1  
    else if d/f2 exists: process d/f2  
    else skip
```

where "process" in this case is:

```
read all the lines and save them for later use
```

What are some idiomatic ways to do this in Scala?

Comment: What you describe is not either, it's either f1, or f2, or both, or none

Comment: Thanks -- edited psuedo-code to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be something like that?

```
fileList.filter(Files.exists(_)).forEach(process(_))
```

Comment: This would process all existing files which isn't the sense of the original code.  <code>fileList.find(Files.exists(_)).fold(()){process(_)}</code> preserves the original.